# How do I install Archiva as a package (apt-get)?

Tags: installation, repository, software-sources

Is it possible to install [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) on Ubuntu using `apt-get` command? I'd like to install the latest stable version.

Is there any Ubuntu repository for Archiva?

Comment: Archiva appears to be distributed using a WAR file (Java servlet). So I guess the most repository-wise way is to install Tomcat using the repositories and install the WAR in Tomcat. I'm not too familiar with installing WARs, but this points you in the right direction probably. It's also available as a standalone package, but usually those are not for running in production.

Comment: I want if a new version of Archiva will coming then that easily update using apt-get install.

Comment: No. There seem to be no `.deb` packages for Archiva. So, without packages not even een repository. Perhaps file this as a feature request or a [Request-For-Package bug](http://www.debian.org/devel/wnpp/) at Debian/Ubuntu to get this into the repository. And no, within a Ubuntu release software won't be upgraded in the repositories - that's the whole point of the Ubuntu release; to freeze the package versions.

Comment: is there a repository that include [Apache Archiva]?

Answer (score 2):

first install tomcat; follow a tutorial on how to install apache2 and tomcat6 or 7,
you can install these VIA apt-get, 
then navigate to `localhost:8080/manager/html`
download the `.war` version of archiva
log into the tomcat manager interface VIA the url provided, 
at the bottom of the page it'll ask you to upload a war file, upload it now, then select deploy.

it will take about a minute and the page will refresh. then you can go to `localhost:8080/archiva`

if you know more about apache you can change the web address.

If it fails to start, monitor the logs with

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out
```